# Format HDFS when adding a node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I have a hdfs setup running in psuedo cluster mode.  If I add an additional data node to I need to run the hdfs format on the new node before or after adding it as an additional slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_have_a_new_node_I_want_to_add_to_a_running_Hadoop_cluster.3B_how_do_I_start_services_on_just_one_node.3F), there is no need to format any node. just do the instructions of the mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to format a Data Node. After adding a Data Node, you should just start that Data Node.

You can only format a Name Node.

Answer (score 0):

No need to format Namenode After adding new datanode. You just need to refresh the nodes by

```
hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes
```